# Gridview Issues

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with four template fields that I need to be able to put info into to save to the database. When I hit the edit button and my columns change into edit mode I can enter information just fine... But when I try to loop through the control to get the information it doesn't pick anything up?

```
Private Sub gvOLIAdj_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvOLIAdjst.RowEditing     
    gvOLIAdjst.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex     
    BindData()  
End Sub
```

Here is the update event that I have so far... any ideas? Am I just not doing this right?

```
Private Sub gvOLIAdj_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvOLIAdjst.RowUpdating     
Dim dts As DataTable = DirectCast(Session("BudgetsTable"), DataTable)     
Dim row As GridViewRow = gvOLIAdjst.Rows(e.RowIndex)     
If DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtItemTempTtlAmt"), TextBox).Text = "" Then           
    lblError.Text = "Invalid Entry. Correct and try again"         
    e.Cancel = True     
Else        
    lblError.Text = ""         
    dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Approval Date") = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtItemTempApprDt"), TextBox).Text         
    dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Total Amount") = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtItemTempTtlAmt"), TextBox).Text         
    dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Comments") = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtItemTempCmmt"), TextBox).Text         
    dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Initials") = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblItemTempInit"), Label).Text          

    gvOLIAdjst.EditIndex = -1         
    BindData()      
End If
If Not IsPostBack Then
        result = dal.dbConnect(sqlconnection, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SQLServerConnection"))
        If result = "Successful" Then
            dt = ExecuteInsertUpdateDeleteStoredProc(sqlconnection, "@amt", txtItemTempApprDt.text)
            dbClose
        End If

    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pulling the controls from the GridView row, I would use the [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) variable that you have access to there.  You can pull the values from the [`NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) property (there are also other useful properties you might need - like `OldValues` and `RowIndex`).

You access them like this:

```
e.NewValues("Data Field Name").ToString()
```

Where "Data Field Name" is the key for that value (the name of the field in your `GridView`s dataset).

Something like this should work

```
dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Approval Date") = e.NewValues("Approval Date").ToString()
dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Total Amount") = e.NewValues("Total Amount").ToString()
dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Comments") = e.NewValues("Comments").ToString()
dts.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Initials") = e.NewValues("Initials").ToString()
```

The keys I'm showing up there might not be exactly right, because I can't see how your binding data to your GridView.  You can set a breakpoint and inspect the "NewValues" dictionary to find the exact keys, I believe.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing this check (if you are getting values from your template controls in rowupdating event):

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

End If
```

Comment: I'm getting any values that is what I am trying to figure out... it doesn't pull the values(information ) from my template fields?